# How to get rid of warnings such as "attrs cannot be resolved as a member of cc"?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, code-completion

How can I get rid of warnings for tags having "cc.attrs.onCompleteJS", "cc.attrs.updateAjax" and "cc.attrs.imageValue"? Each warning has same explanation as "attrs cannot be resolved as a member of cc". I use JSF 2.x as a framework and Eclipse as an editor.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="imageValue"></composite:attribute>
    <composite:attribute name="updateAjax"></composite:attribute>
    <composite:attribute name="onCompleteJS"></composite:attribute> 
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="regionTreeComponent.css"></h:outputStylesheet>      
    <table style="width: 100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">
                <p:autoComplete forceSelection="true" id="sTxtRegionName" value="#{regionTreeBean.sRegionName}" 
                completeMethod="#{regionTreeBean.completeRegionName}" styleClass="sTxtRegionName" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <p:commandButton styleClass="rSearchButton"  id="iconOnly" icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#{regionTreeBean.searchSelectNode}" 
                oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.onCompleteJS}" update=":mainForm:treeComponent:regionTree #{cc.attrs.updateAjax}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr style="width: 100%;"></hr>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h:graphicImage styleClass="headerImage" library="images" name="#{cc.attrs.imageValue}"></h:graphicImage>
        <p:outputLabel styleClass="headerLabel" value="#{msgs['treeComponent.regions']}"></p:outputLabel>
    </div>
    <p:tree value="#{regionTreeBean.rootNode}" var="node"
    animate="true" selection="#{regionTreeBean.selectedNode}"
    selectionMode="single" styleClass="tree" id="regionTree">
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{regionTreeBean.onNodeSelect}" update="#{cc.attrs.updateAjax}" oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.onCompleteJS}" />
        <p:treeNode styleClass="slTreeNode" icon="region">
            <h:outputText value="#{node.REGION_NAME}"/>
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>   
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Tried the latest?

Comment: @BalusC , Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819. Eclipse produces new versions in a short time, that's why my eclipse might have been out-of-date.

Comment: That's definitely not the latest. Eclipse produces new versions only once per year. Try the latest first to exclude an already long fixed bug or implemented missing feature from being the cause. Any time you encounter odd or missing behavior, always make sure everything is up to date.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations.